# Correct procedure for restarting local MongoDB when Mongoose schema is changed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi all I'm new to learning how to develop with Node.js using Mongoose and Express. I have been having some issues with Mongodb not correctly reflecting my schema changes.

For example, I have written a model that supposedly auto-increment `_id` by 1 starting from 0 when each new document is inserted. I'm testing a few ways to do this model and so I'm constantly inserting different data.

I drop the collection each time to try to reinsert the data. However, `_id` instead of starting at 0, it starts at the previous largest `_id`.

This is just one of the issues that I have encountered. Some other similar Schema changes that I did on the fly also were not reflected.

I tried the following:

- Ending npm/nodemon
- Ctrl+C from `mongo`
- shutdownServer from `mongo`

Is there something else that I need to shut down completely then restart before mongoose reflects the newest form of the schema? Thanks!

Comment: How are you implementing auto-increment, given that MongoDB doesn't support such a thing out of the box?

Comment: this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: I am facing the same issue. And it's incredibly frustrating. This should be native to mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start fresh with a new schema, it's best (if possible) to drop the old database entirely (`db.dropDatabase()` from the MongoDB shell), otherwise you may run into various issues (that can also be solved separately, if dropping the database isn't an option):

- left-over collections, like the one used by the autoincrement plugin that you're using (I think it'll use a collection called `identitycounters`);
- left-over indexes, which happens when you define field names in your schema that should be indexed, and you subsequently rename or delete one of those fields;

Restarting the database server won't solve these, they do require some manual administration.

Comment: Thanks I guess this problem was particular to my choice of mongoose-auto-increment. I played around with the `identitycounters` collection and I could just manually reset the beginning count for the collection I would like to "restart."

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but you can reset the counter from your model as well, see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment#want-to-reset-counter-back-to-the-start-value).